# Redis mget showing in SLOWLOG

Tags: c++, redis

I am using redis to store some json values against unique string keys. Due to some requirement i had to fetch multiple key-value pair (precisely 15 K) in 1 go for which i used MGET redis command using C++ and cpp_redis.

The system is working fine but there is some issue in timing. MGET is slow, i am observing a latency of around 200+ ms in c++ and it is also showing in SLOWLOG.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SLOWLOG GET
1) 1) (integer) 893
    2) (integer) 1518509153
    3) (integer) 167090
    4)  1) "MGET"
    2) "2be1d3559aa1c93b7b84b144c82c048d"
    3) "ac37b25293276382a1eb9fb634bd1ece"
    4) "b7257ed986e23dc3bfc630ace592be7c"
    5) "e6f92ac1c8c7734d22473d9648863b88"
    6) "98b3077022d5a32fbb3df4434ac6a3ed"
    7) "00de037007eef73d97e648daa06e5ffb"
    8) "60e7fb8be50c543012243cb204cb8694"
    9) "6a99e16b15ba6a65801a777cbb19bc3e"
   10) "68e1c22474db63f925f2c1fe14f5d2d6"
   11) "b12e2cbb1330b1b73d6a0108e5f82062"
   12) "cc29fe2f71770848dfc1b8bec955523c"
   13) "6e3d9bf3be3b70b38058f0e345a330dd"
   14) "a6642a96fae7ccd4fe368dc58bc04bee"
   15) "54e04e4d08b69fee6f73adf56d5548ec"
   16) "64412a5def4407fe71ba0864898c1c10"
   17) "3f2435bfbd23d264b2e2bef22e68b014"
   18) "4c70944023f9e6fb6e55fffb9c1f0156"
   19) "9dfdb0f0ea8151016f335eaefb5c38a4"
   20) "1f9b8a6e35e985e335b5eb223ce170d3"
   21) "6e40a2d1e7016a19ea04711f38de793e"
   22) "ec8228f23fe0c05caef99dc43c0ec699"
   23) "20c1e4239912b7aa6fb4930ee36e49f4"
   24) "5d64ed638091eb658d16f5f1cd8575ae"
   25) "4176452c864d229b7c4190cea8187717"
   26) "b4ece113856f220dc15bfd4b8ed605e8"
   27) "e015e9f10e14f31cb5a09525f86d57b1"
   28) "360507bac0e7e8bd0d73ed7edf777663"
   29) "18b7d6ca197a01c5773d3cbe204fef8d"
   30) "0f3d1d8db2c712f11644240a10e885e0"
   31) "b9d91378fff3a19544c482233df1268f"
   32) "... (14970 more arguments)"
```

Is there any best practice or particular thing which could be done to make this call fast.

Answer (score 3):

MGET depends on two factors:

1. The number of keys you fetch. Each fetch is O(1) so N fetches is O(N) of course. 1000 keys will be ~10 times slower than 100 keys. No way around it
2. The size of each object - the bigger the objects are, the more time it takes to serialize the response.

15K objects for one MGET is quite a lot. In this case, in order not to block redis, I'd actually try to split it into smaller batches and do several queries, let's say 1000 each. It will slow down the time one client fetches data, but will make redis not block for 200ms which is really bad.

Comment: Basically you are suggesting chunking the key array, but if done sequentially it will be time consuming and for concurrently will need to launch threads in each api request is also not a good idea.

Comment: @NirmalVatsyayan suppose you have 100 clients working, some of them having smaller requests like writing an object. If the longer requests block redis for 200ms each, your short requests will also block for that long. If you split it into many smaller requests, the long ones will take a bit longer (not a lot), but the shorter ones will finish much faster. There is no other way to accelerate this, in short.